# Firebase Anonymous Authentication store ID

Tags: firebase, authentication, unity-game-engine, firebase-authentication, anonymous

I was wondering how exactely does Firebase anonymous auth work? When the user starts my app it signs in anonymously with auth.SignInAnonymously() but everytime he restarts the app, it will generate a new ID. How do I log the user in with the same ID (i.e. related on the deviceID or something similar).

The service Playfab for example has three functions: LoginWithIOSDeviceID, LoginWithAndroidDeviceID, and LoginWithCustomId. That would make things a lot easier. How could I solve that with Firebase Auth? I would need some kind of auth for the Database because of following rule:

```
{
  "rules": {
    "users": {
      "$uid": {
        ".write": "$uid === auth.uid"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Thank you very much for your help!
Best regards!

Comment: I develop with the Android SDK, not Unity, but would expect anonymous signin to work the same.  The behavior you describe is not what I see on Android and is at odds with [the Unity SDK documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/unity/class/firebase/auth/firebase-auth#signinanonymouslyasync), which says, _If there is already an anonymous user signed in, that user will be returned_.  If you don't sign-out the user, the UID should persist across restarts.

Comment: If a user is signed in anonymously and you call `signInAnonymously()` again, the same user should be returned, unless you had called `signOut()`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hello and thanks for the answers. Meanwhile I had a talk with firebase support and we found the error. I called the login right after init of auth but before it was able to restore the session from Cache.

To give more context, when a user authenticates, the SDK will get an ID Token which is the one used for making authenticated requests. It has a 1 hour expiration time. The SDK will also get a Refresh Token and the SDK will use it to get a new ID Token once the current is about to expire. The SDK will handle this automatically and for the user it will look like the session never expires. When a user opens the app, the current ID Token will be probably expired, so the SDK will grab the stored ID Token and Refresh Token and it will get a new ID Token if required.

Now after I wait for the return of the restore session thread it works as it's supposed to work :-)

Thanks again for your answers!